# Wordpress - Dates working incorrectly

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress theme and having this strange issue with the post dates. On the `index.php` page, the post that I insert does show the date (Check the figure)

[image]

But as soon as I add a new post the dae of this previous post disappears (Check the figure below)

[image]

You can see that the date of the newly added post is being shown but the previous post's date has disappeared. The code I'm using is:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Above is the code placed in the `index.php` file and below is the `content.php` file's code

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <li <?php post_class("blog-page-post span12"); ?> id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-thumb span4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <article class="preview-details <?php echo has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID()) ? "span8" : "span12"; ?>">
                <p class="article-meta"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_date(get_option("date_format")); ?></p>
                <h3 class="playlist-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h3>
                <p class="excerpt"><?php echo string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), 55); ?></p>

            </article>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <p class="article-meta article-foot-meta muted pull-right">
                    <?php the_category("&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;"); ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

PS: Both the posts have the same format, if that's what you think.

Comment: Both post dates are same?

Comment: Yes, both the posts have same date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag the_time() with a date-specific format string.

```
<?php  the_time('F j, Y \a\t g:i a');  ?> or

<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try with the following

```
 <?php  the_time('F j, Y \a\t g:i a');  ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a good look at your answer i.e. you'd used `the_time(get_option('date_format'))` worked for me as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress documentation mentiones that "When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post". Try using

```
<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
```

That should solve your problem :)